# FormatException when trying to write string to database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, barcode

I am writting a small web application and I want to add some details to my database using a web form. I am using asp.net and c# to create this web application and visual studio 2013 as developing tool. I am using a barcode scanner to scan the barcode from a product. Because i can not include a screenshot  from my user interface, i have 3 labels, 3 textboxes (Barcode,Description,Price), a add button and i have created a database to save my details. My 3 colums in the database is `Barcode`, `Description`, `Price` and their data types are `varchar(50)`, `varchar(50)`, `decimal(10,2)`. When I run the page and scan the barcode i get an exception:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

I have tried it without the barcode scanner and put the barcode by keyboard and is working fine.

Here are  more details from the exception:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Input string was not in a correct format.   Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack
>
> trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 31:             con.Open(); Line 32:  Line 33:
>   da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); Line 34:  Line 35:
>   con.Close();
>
> Source File:  path.aspx.cs    Line:  33
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean
>
> parseDecimal) +11177559    System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value,
>   NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +172
>   System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value, IFormatProvider provider) +67
>   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
>   +10    System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +11043185
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType
>   destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed,
>
> Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming) +5332823
>
> [FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a
>   Decimal.]    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object
>   value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed,
>
> Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming) +5331815
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue() +185
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean
>   isCommandProc) +102
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildParamList(TdsParser parser,
>   SqlParameterCollection parameters) +201
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildExecuteSql(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String commandText, SqlParameterCollection
>
> parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc) +237
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean
>
> returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean
>   asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean
>
> returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32
>   timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean
>
> sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +208
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +163
>   PosSystem.Stock.addStock.btnAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   path\add.aspx.cs:33
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9615682
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +103
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> +1724

Any one has an idea why is that and how i can fix it please?

Here is my code for when the button is clicked:

```
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int y;
        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(@Barcode,@Description,@Price)", con);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Barcode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBarcode.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtDescription.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtPPrice.Text;
        con.Open();

        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you use `.Value = decimal.Parse(txtPPrice.Text);`? Show the value that was entered in the `TextBox`. You can always use `decimal.TryParse` to validate input.

Comment: What is the value of `txtPPrice.Text` exactly and what is your `CurrentCulture`? And you need `@` sign in `Barcode` in your `SqlCommand`.

Comment: I get the same error but for the decimal now. i think is not the price the problem is the barcode scanner. Because i have remove the barcode textfield and it was working perfect. It did save the details to the database. Is just when i scan the barcode it gets me this error. When I enter the barcode by keyboard is fine.

Comment: Yeah i have fix that(@). My txt.PPrice is to enter the price of the product. I think i don't have a current culture, not sure what it is.

Comment: @user3310040 Besides your question: I **strongly encourage** you to think about proper layering - You should not, except for simple demos, write directly to the db, as the logic is to tightly coupled to a webb-application (no testing possible, no exchanging of mssql vs mysql...)

Comment: @user3310040: have you used the debugger, what value was entered? Does it contains spaces at the beginning or end? If so, remove it with `Trim()`. Perhaps the barcode scanner sends some characters at the end which you could stop in the driver.

Comment: @user3310040 Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not". Please try to find a more meaningful title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line...

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtPPrice.Text;
```

Seems to be the problem. you are trying to save text to a decimal field. it could work if the value of the string is convertible to a decimal by the sql driver but on this occasion it is failing. maybe because the price string contains currency formatting (e.g. £, $).

Try parsing this as a decimal first

Comment: I am not entering any symbols in front of it. The problem is the barcode scanner, because as I said above the problem is when i scan the barcode through the barcode scanner. I think is like pressing enter after is scanning the barcode. Because when I enter the barcode manually is ok. It let me save the details.

Comment: @user3310040 the stack trace holds the answer. it says... `[FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.]`
this is what it is failing on. I would try to cleanse all the data before inserting it. try to parse the price as a decimal and maybe debug all the values as they are getting put into the database to make sure they are what you expected

Comment: It worked and i found out that my scanner is pressing enter after scanning the barcode. Do you know how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but -- I encounter code like this all the time and the issue is allowing .NET and Sql to coerce values.

I think that you are still not focusing on the real issue, which is that you are relying on coercion of data that you have not validated. You can certainly Trim any white space, however -- if you would do the conversion yourself, you would cover far more ground than by trying to bat away the input issues in favor of writing more defensive code.

I usually keep a "Sandbox" ready to test things like this outside of the application. Have a look at this code...it is far from perfect, however -- it illustrates some flags you can pass to TryParse that will save you tons of head scratching and frustration.

```
    Dim theProblemWithTheData As String = String.Format("$-123.45{0}", vbCrLf)
Dim dontDoThis As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("fakeParameter",
                                                         SqlDbType.Decimal)
Dim doThis As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("betterFakeParameter",
                                                     SqlDbType.Decimal)
Dim doThisValue As Decimal

Try
  dontDoThis.Value = theProblemWithTheData
  Dim success As Boolean = Decimal.TryParse(theProblemWithTheData,
                                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
                                            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                            doThisValue)

  If success Then
    doThis.Value = doThisValue
  End If

Catch ex As Exception
  Dim exInfo As String = ex.ToString
End Try
```